# cancancan: authorize_resource gets called to early

Tags: cancancan

I would like to use [authorize_resource](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/CanCan%2FControllerAdditions%2FClassMethods:authorize_resource) but not [load_and_authorize_resource](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/CanCan/ControllerAdditions/ClassMethods#load_and_authorize_resource-instance_method).

I now have the same issue as this person [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45038310/cancancan-authorize-resource-not-working-as-expected). But instead of setting the @model param inside the action I am using a before_action filter:

```
class ModelsController

  before_action :set_model

  authorize_resource

  def show; end

  private

  def set_model
    @model = Model.find(params[:model_id])
  end
end
```

authorize_resource still checks for Model instead of @model because it is not set. How do I resolve this? I tried changing the order of authorize_resource and the before_action, didn't work. I tried using prepend_before_action, didn't work.

I know that I can use load_and_authorize_resource or check the ability manually with authorize! :show, @model, but that is not what I want.

Is there any way to always execute the before_filter before authorize_resource?

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that the id_param wasn't called :id, but :model_id instead.

using

`authorize_resource id_param: :model_id`

fixes the issue. Currently the id_param is not documented.